# How magento calculate tax on product in reorder from admin ? Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-calculation, reorder

How tax is calculated for products on reorder page in admin ?

[image]

I am trying to get the flow how the tax are calculated on reorder page,
I am using Avatax module, & found a bug that on reorder the product tax amount is different from original.

Any thoughts how its been calculated by magento ? ASAP

Comment: any views on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?